# how to rename picked property in MappedType

Tags: typescript, nestjs

i need to adapt the nestJS PickType so that it allows rename some properties
https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types

following this example

```
interface Type<T = any> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

declare function PickType<T, K extends keyof T>(classRef: Type<T>, keys: readonly K[]): Type<Pick<T, typeof keys[number]>>;


class AClazz {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: number;
}

const piked = PickType(AClazz, [
  'a',
 'c',
] as const);


piked is 
{
 a: string,
 c: number
}
```

i need rename only certain properties, for example rename c to d obtaining

```
const piked = PickType(AClazz, [
  'a',
 'c' as 'd',
] as const);


piked is 
{
 a: string,
 d: number
}
```

if the original key exists and is picked

```
  class AClazz {
      a: string;
      b: string;
      c: number;
      d: string;
    }

    const piked = PickType(AClazz, [
      'a',
     'c' as 'd', //ERROR 'd' exists and is being picked
     'd',
    ] as const);
```

if the original key exists but isn´t picked

```
class AClazz {
      a: string;
      b: string;
      c: number;
      d: string;
    }
    const piked = PickType(AClazz, [
      'a',
     'c' as 'd',
    ] as const);
    
    piked is 
    {
     a: string,
     d: number
    }
```

Comment: Does it matter if the original key still exists? e.g. You have `a`, `c`, and `d` in the `picked` class

Comment: If the original key exists but is not picked then it should let you continue.  If is picked then it should show an error related to a property with that name already exists and was already picked.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel could you help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your answer to my question

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I updated the original question with more examples